# How can I rotate the wheel image using CAKeyFrameAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm implementing the Animation project. I have an image wheel.png. How can i rotate this image using CAKeyFrameAnimation.I already rotate this image using CABasicAnimation.

Comment: Just edited my answer. Please check the code and let me know if you need any help with it or if that works for you. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is tutorial on ray's site that shows a step by step of how to create a rotating wheel. Check the sample code for rotating animation. That may be what you are looking for.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit

Although it uses `UIKit` but you get the idea.

Edit:

Here is a sample code using `CAKeyFrameAnimation` that rotates an image continually, you can play around with it to perform what you like. Hope this helps you out.

```
UIImageView *tempView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 80, 80)];
tempView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon"];
tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:tempView];

const NSUInteger rotations = 10;
const NSTimeInterval duration  = 5;

CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
CGFloat touchUpStartAngle = 0;
CGFloat touchUpEndAngle = (M_PI);
CGFloat angularVelocity = (((2 * M_PI) * rotations) + M_PI) / duration;
anim.values = @[@(touchUpStartAngle), @(touchUpStartAngle + angularVelocity * duration)];
anim.duration = duration;
anim.autoreverses = NO;
anim.delegate = self;
anim.repeatCount = 1;
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
[tempView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"test"];

tempView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(touchUpStartAngle +     (touchUpEndAngle));
```

Comment: I referred raywendrlich animation tutorial.But they not implemented CAKeyFrameAnimation animation class. I want rotate the wheel using CAKeyFrameAnimation.

Comment: I know that. I thought you may like a easier way to rotate your image. If your are set in using CAKeyAnimation I will update my answer in a while with some codes. Otherwise you can use the easier way.

Comment: I have already done with CABasicAnimation.It works fine.Please update your code using CAKeyFrameAnimation.

Comment: I tried your code.its working fine.I have one more doubt how to reduce the wheel rotation speed.

Comment: You need to play around with the numbers in const method. Set them higher to slow down the wheel. If my answer was helpful please check mark it as the correct answer.:)

Comment: The wheel is rotate in forward. I want to rotate wheel in full and full backward.How to do this.

Comment: That's easy, use - for end rotation and it turns counter clock wise.